# setrlimit fails and rlim_max is 0

Tags: c++, linux

We are using a third party product that has the following code. The result of setrlimit is EINVAL and the value of rlim_max is 0. I tried to read the man page for setrlimit but could not understand what this could mean and how to solve it.

```
rlimit Limit;
if (getrlimit(RLIMIT_CORE, &Limit) != 0)
{
    return;
}

Limit.rlim_cur = RLIM_INFINITY;
setrlimit(RLIMIT_CORE, &Limit);
```

Comment: What is the `Resource` you try to change? Please try to create a [mre] to show us.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Very good question, I should have checked that. I will update the question as soon as I have the answer to that.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Question updated, the resource is RLIMIT_CORE

Comment: Perhaps the sysadmin of your system have configured a global hard limit of zero, which means you can't change the soft limit. If you run the `prlimit` command, what does it say?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Unfortunately that is not an easy task, our server is hosted by a third party and we have no control/access to these servers. So you think this could be a Linux configuration issue?

Comment: That's probably a reason. Allowing core-dumps could easily fill up a drive, so remote hosting companies tend to disable it. If you have a program that crashes and that you need to debug, then I suggest you add much more logging (this is generally allowed, as while it could easily write a lot of data at least it's not a full memory dump of the process for each crash)., so you can easier pinpoint the location and perhaps even the data or input. Then you have a possibility to replicate the crash locally where you have access to a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by increasing RAM on server.